# Can't seem to get Element.setAttribute to work with webpack/babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, draggable, babeljs

I have the following:

```
Element.prototype.makeDraggable = (elem = null) => {
    //this.draggable = true;
    this.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    this.ondragstart = (e) => { e.dataTransfer.setData("text", elem ? elem.id : e.target.id); }
};
```

When the browser gets to that function it throws an error on the first line:

> Drag.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: n.setAttribute is not a function

Where `n` is the minified name of the element, or so I thought.

[image]

as you can see in the picture, `this` seems to be an `Element`, but `n` is.. well I don't know what it is. Am I doing it wrong?

At this same point, if I do `this.draggable = true` *in the console* it works just fine... You can also see that I tried doing it in the code but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `this` you see in the debugger is the *actual* `this` value; the `this` you see in the source view is the source-mapped version of `n`, and the value of `n` isn’t what you want it to be.

You used an arrow function, so you got lexical `this`. That’s what arrow functions do. To access the `this` from call time (what’s generally intended when adding methods to a prototype), use a non-arrow function:

```
Element.prototype.makeDraggable = function (elem = null) {
    //this.draggable = true;
    this.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    this.ondragstart = (e) => { e.dataTransfer.setData("text", elem ? elem.id : e.target.id); }
};
```

See also [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable).

Finally, extending the prototypes you have some of the least control over – browser built-ins – is considered a bad idea. (You could produce a conflict with future extensions to the spec, for example – or with other libraries you use.) A standalone function usually works better:

```
const makeDraggable = (target, elem = null) {
    target.draggable = true;
    target.ondragstart = (e) => { e.dataTransfer.setData("text", elem ? elem.id : e.target.id); }
};
```